# IN clause param to subquery

Tags: sql, oracle, subquery

Following query gives me latest date/time of the particular day.

```
select * 
from calendar c 
where c.date= to_date('2018/03/09','yyyy/mm/dd') 
 and c.date >= all(select date from calendar c2 where c.date = c2.date)
```

how can I use above query as subquery and pass in clause as a param to the following query?

```
select * from (

/*above query inside and iterate over in param*/

)abc where abc.date in (to_date('2018/03/09','yyyy/mm/dd') ,to_date('2018/03/10','yyyy/mm/dd') )
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I do not know if I understood you correctly. Is this what you want to do?

```
SELECT * FROM (
    SELECT * 
    FROM calendar c 
    WHERE c.d_date= to_date('2018/03/09','yyyy/mm/dd') 
            AND c.d_date >= all(SELECT d_date FROM calendar c2 WHERE c.d_date = c2.d_date)
)abc WHERE abc.d_date IN (to_date('2018/03/09','yyyy/mm/dd') ,to_date('2018/03/10','yyyy/mm/dd') );
```

I changed the name of the date column to d_date, because it is a reserved word.

Answer (score 0):

```
select * 
from calendar c 
where c.date in (to_date('2018/03/09','yyyy/mm/dd') ,to_date('2018/03/10','yyyy/mm/dd') )
 and c.date >= all(select date from calendar c2 where c.date = c2.date)
```

Try this.

Answer (score 0):

sorry i meant to parameterize subquery using outer query and was able to write some thing like which serves the purpose

```
select * 
from calendar c 
where c.date >= all(select date from calendar c2 where c.date = c2.date) 
and c.date in (to_date('2018/03/09','yyyy/mm/dd'),to_date('2018/03/10','yyyy/mm/dd') )
```